# WPF C# Get text from a Textblock inside a ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, textblock

How can i access a Textblock inside a Stackpanel that is inside a ListBoxItem?

For example:

```
ListBoxItem MyItem = new ListBoxItem();
StackPanel StackPnl = new StackPanel();
TextBlock Title = new TextBlock();

Title.Text = "Item 1";

StackPnl.Children.Add(Title);
MyItem.Content = StackPnl;
```

How can i later access the Text property of that Textblock with Listbox.SelectedItem?

Comment: how about `((MyItem.Content as StackPanel).Children[0] as TextBlock).Text = "foo"` or simply `Title.Text = "foo"`?

Comment: Keep a reference to TextBlock for later use? Why do you want to do that at all? And why are you creating these elements in code instead of setting the ListBox's ItemTemplate in XAML and bind the TextBlock's Text property to a view model item property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//listBox1 is your ListBox
ListBoxItem MyItem = listBox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
if(MyItem != null)
{
    StackPanel sp = MyItem.Content as StackPanel;
    if(sp != null && sp.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = sp.Children[0] as TextBlock;
        if(textBlock != null)
        {
            string text = textBlock.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my dude :)